# What happend to the visual XSD editor in to the Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, xsd

Visual Studio 2005 has an excellent visual XSD editor:

[VS 2005 XSD Editor http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/7382/clipboard01ics.png](http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/7382/clipboard01ics.png)

In VS 2008 I cannot find it anymore ...

Comment: They stupidly removed it, but it still does not make this a programming question, next!

Comment: Not a programming question ???? I DO programming in VS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The XML Schema Editor was taken out of
>   VS2008 for various reasons.  We are
>   planning to replace it with a new
>   designer in a future version.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/84212ff1-ca41-4a86-bc0a-fe9d59b902f9